# Вычисляемые имена свойств и useState react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook, setstate

Собственно вопрос в том, как мне с помощью хука состояния заполнить объект состояния значениями из нескольки импутов.
Вот код, чтобы было понятнее:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState()

  const handlChang = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name
    const value = e.target.value

    setState({
      [name]: value
    })

  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <input onChange={handlChang} name='firstInput'></input>
        <input onChange={handlChang} name='ScondInput'></input>
        <input onChange={handlChang} name='ThirdInput'></input>
        <input onChange={handlChang} name='fourthInput'></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Возможно как-то использовать вместе с useEffect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState()

  const handlChang = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name
    const value = e.target.value

    setState(prev => {
      return {
      ...prev,
      [name]: value
    }
    })

  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <input onChange={handlChang} name='firstInput'></input>
        <input onChange={handlChang} name='ScondInput'></input>
        <input onChange={handlChang} name='ThirdInput'></input>
        <input onChange={handlChang} name='fourthInput'></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Используя предыдущее состояние

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Только без ретерна не работало.

Comment: Да упустил!Спасибо